# Can byobu run with specific window size and location?

Tags: multiple-monitors, autostart, byobu

On my Ubuntu 14.04, I am using 2 monitors: Main and sub.

I also set `byobu` as a start-up application:

[image]

Is it possible to start `byobu` maximized on the sub monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A. find out a geometry for your terminal:**

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --geometry=800x800+1921+0
                                   (width x height + x location + y location)

*x location = width of main + x location of sub
*to check width and height of a terminal, run `stty size`
```

**B. open terminal with specific command:**

1. right click on terminal -> profile -> profile preference
2. on `title and command` tab, check `run a custom command instead of my shell`
3. enter custom command: `/usr/bin/byobu`

**C. add command to startup application:**

1. run `gnome-session-properties`
2. add startup program
3. enter command from **A** `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --geometry=800x800+1921+0`